# Intermitent WCF service timeout exception

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a WCF service hosted in Windows service and a single non-threaded client accessing the service.  The service is performing data access to a SQL Server 2008 database.  Intermitently the following exception occurs on the client side:

```
System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

I am aware that this error can be a bit of a catch all for WCF problems but I am certain that the error is not occuring because the operation takes over a minute (I have trippled the timeout and it still occurs).

The problem has occurred on multiple endpoints and occurs on the call to the client proxy.  I logged to a text file the various points the service reaches when the crash occurs and see that the return statement from the service is reached.

The client and service have been in use in some form for over two years and this problem appears to have occurred only recently and without any obivious changes in areas significant to the service (although both of these statements are danagerous to rely on when debugging a problem).

Any advice, thoughts or suggestions to investigate would be appreciated.

Here is the service binding:

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
    allowCookies="false">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
      enabled="false" />
  <security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

and here is the client binding:

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAssessmentDataAccessContract"
         closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
    <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
            <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
        </transport>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" 
                 algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
    </security> 
</binding>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a service that connected to an Oracle database.  The culprit took me some time to find, but the first step I would take would be to enable tracing on both the server and the client.  [Here is the MSDN doc on how to do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).  [Jump to the recomended settings for tracing in production environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx)

What it sounds like is that you have a value TYPE in the database that WCF does not know how to serialize, or it is not included in the KnownTypes attribute of your ServiceContract.  When I ran into this issue, it was very similar, but I needed to dig through the traces to find that something was not being serialized (or deserialized) properly on the call.  My problem was in returning a dataset instead of a specific value, it was harder to find exactly what data was the culprit.

If you do not have a custom error handler, WCF is prone to locking up on an exception and your client with get a "timeout".

Comment: I have looked at the traces and so far not seen anything that would point me in the direction of a solution.  What gave away that you had a KnownTypes issues?

Comment: Actually, we had to set up debug on both the client and the server.  When we found that it seemed like one side would send but the other never recieved anything, we turned on tracing to the fullest ability.  After some major digging, we discovered that the end sending could not serialize the data and would kick out an exception somewhere way outside of our code.  Given that, we looked at the exact call to the database, and what was coming back and reproduced the problem with a specific data type (DBNull, stupid right?) which we then added to known types.

Answer (score 1):

> when the crash occurs and see that the return statement from the service is reached.

That helps but doesn't mean the server side isn't causing/adding to the problem.
Is it possible your method returns a very large payload and it takes too long to download or exceeds the maximum size of the WCF bindings?

Now, the reason you might not have seen this until now is NOW you have 2 years worth of data so you may be returning more stuff than you did initally. Just a guess.

eg

```
public string GetStuff()
{
     return //large payload
}
```

what do you bindings look like on *both* ends? Wwhat is the value of `maxStringContentLength` ?

Comment: Added the service and client bindings to the question.

Comment: @AlanBradbury how big *could* the messages be? Using reliable sessions on a very slow connection (<5k) with large messages can cause issues.

Comment: actually i can see a possible error in your client side config. see this part `maxStringContentLength="8192"` - that should match your server side setting of `2147483647` - in fact all those settings in that element should match.